# all magento2 command error

Tags: error, command-line, magento2.3.2

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\Framework\Cache\FrontendInterface in /home/chicpla1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50
Stack trace:
#0 /home/chicpla1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\\Framewo...')
#1 /home/chicpla1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(160): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Framewo...')
#2 /home/chicpla1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(246): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument(Array, 'Magento\\Framewo...', NULL, 'cache', 'Magento\\Framewo...')
#3 /home/chicpla1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime('Magento\\Framewo...', Array, Arr in /home/chicpla1/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php on line 50
```

Comment: can you please provide screenshot of your terminal where you're firing this commands?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ojqbqc

Answer (score 1):

If you use redis, run:

```
redis-cli flushall
```

or you'll need to run the following commands:

- Clear `generated`
- Clear `var/cache`
- Enable Magento modules: `php bin/magento module:enable --all`
- Run these commands

> php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:di:compile
>
> php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:clean
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

**I hope this will help**

Comment: but not commad found error
all php command error

Comment: Have you cleared the cache and generated folder before running the command `php bin/magento module:enable --all`. Secondly you only run this command `redis-cli flushall` if you have redis setup and running

Comment: but generate same error